# RxJs operator, forkJoin shows error with more than 6 parameters in Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my angular form I have some collection type properties. The properties are given below:

```
countries: CountryInfo[] = [];
floorLists: VariableInfo[] = [];
memberTypes: VariableInfo[] = [];
memberCategories: VariableInfo[] = [];
businessTypes: VariableInfo[] = [];
voterRelations: VariableInfo[] = [];
bloodGroups: VariableInfo[] = [];
designations: VariableInfo[] = [];
```

Now I have used forkJoin operator to call service to populate the above properties with data. But it seems that whenever **I put more than 6 parameters in forkJoin operator with different types**, the operator shows an error. Below is the code

```
let countries$ = this.countryService.getCountryLists();
let floors$ = this.variableService.getFloorLists();
let memberTypes$ = this.variableService.getMemberTypeLists();
let categories$ = this.variableService.getMemberCategoryLists();
let businessTypes$ = this.variableService.getBusinessTypeLists();
let voterRelations$ = this.variableService.getVoterRelationLists();
let bloodGroups$ = this.variableService.getBloodGroupLists();
let designations$ = this.variableService.getDesignations();

forkJoin([countries$, floors$, memberTypes$, categories$, businessTypes$, voterRelations$, bloodGroups$, designations$]).subscribe(data => {
    this.countries = data[0];
    this.floorLists = data[1];
    this.memberTypes = data[2];
    this.memberCategories = data[3];
    this.businessTypes = data[4];
    this.voterRelations = data[5];
    this.bloodGroups = data[6];
    this.designations = data[7];
});
```

It shows the below errors.

> TS2322: Type 'CountryInfo[] | VariableInfo[]' is not assignable to
> type 'CountryInfo[]'.   Type 'VariableInfo[]' is not assignable to
> type 'CountryInfo[]'.
> Type 'VariableInfo' is missing the following properties from type 'CountryInfo': Name, Flag, Code
>
> 217       this.countries = data[0];
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve that using another overload of the `forkJoin`, because the one you're using requires the observable array items to be from the same type.

The following overload should works:

```js
forkJoin({
  countries: countries$,
  floors: floors$,
  memberTypes: memberTypes$,
  categories: categories$,
  businessTypes: businessTypes$,
  voterRelations: voterRelations$,
  bloodGroups: bloodGroups$,
  designations: designations$,
}).subscribe((data) => {
  this.countries = data.countries;
  this.floorLists = data.floors;
  this.memberTypes = data.memberTypes;
  this.memberCategories = data.categories;
  this.businessTypes = data.businessTypes;
  this.voterRelations = data.voterRelations;
  this.bloodGroups = data.bloodGroups;
  this.designations = data.designations;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `data` inside `subscribe()` is of type `Array<CountryInfo[] | VariableInfo[]>`. So referring to the array with the index `data[i]` infers the type `CountryInfo[] | VariableInfo[]`, hence the error.

You can use array destructuring to have more specific types, which should fix the error.

```
forkJoin([countries$, floors$, memberTypes$, categories$, businessTypes$, voterRelations$, bloodGroups$, designations$])
.subscribe(([countries, floors, memberTypes, categories, businessTypes, voterRelations, bloodGroups, designations]) => {
    this.countries = countries;
    this.floorLists = floors;
    this.memberTypes = memberTypes;
    this.memberCategories = categories;
    this.businessTypes = businessTypes;
    this.voterRelations = voterRelations;
    this.bloodGroups = bloodGroups;
    this.designations = designations;
});
```

Comment: It's not working. The error is still there.

Comment: What does IntelleSense show when you hover over `countries` in the subscribe block?

Answer (score 1):

## `ForkJoin` with a Dictionary instead of an Array

Positional arguement in an array are fairly error-prone. ForkJoin lets you solve this problem **and** the problem with types in one fell swoop. As long as the keys match, you can re-order the inputs without fear. It also stops you from re-typing the names over and over and over again.

```ts
forkJoin({
  countries: this.countryService.getCountryLists(),
  floorLists: this.variableService.getFloorLists(),
  memberTypes: this.variableService.getMemberTypeLists(),
  memberCategories: this.variableService.getMemberCategoryLists(),
  businessTypes: this.variableService.getBusinessTypeLists(),
  voterRelations: this.variableService.getVoterRelationLists(),
  bloodGroups: this.variableService.getBloodGroupLists(),
  designations: this.variableService.getDesignations()
}).subscribe(data => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    this[key] = value;
  }
});
```

Of course, the obj here can be pulled out of the forkjoin and built (incrementally or otherwise) elsewhere. In this case make sure you type "callListType" properly somewhere so your code knows what to expect (Is voterRelations an optional field are there numerous types at play?)

```ts
let callList: callListType =  {
  countries: this.countryService.getCountryLists(),
  floorLists: this.variableService.getFloorLists(),
  memberTypes: this.variableService.getMemberTypeLists(),
  memberCategories: this.variableService.getMemberCategoryLists(),
  businessTypes: this.variableService.getBusinessTypeLists()
}
callList = {...callList, voterRelations: this.variableService.getVoterRelationLists()};
callList.bloodGroups = this.variableService.getBloodGroupLists();
callList["designations"] = this.variableService.getDesignations();

forkJoin(callList).subscribe(data => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    this[key] = value;
  }
});
```

Comment: How can I assign values to my properties?

Comment: @mnu-nasir, what do you mean? That's what I do in the for-loop `this[key] = value;`. It's already in the examples above.